# AUCTeX auto style files for .dtx and .tex with the same base name

Tags: auctex, package-writing, docstrip

In a LaTeX package using DocStrip with pretty standard structure one could have the following files:

```
mypackage-code.tex
mypackage.dtx
mypackage.ins
mypackage.tex
```

`mypackage.dtx` is the main file where the code is and from which the `.sty` is extracted, according to instructions in `mypackage.ins`. `mypackage-code.tex` is just a wrapper around `mypackage.dtx`:

```tex
\documentclass{l3doc}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}

\DocInput{mypackage.dtx}

\end{document}
```

So that we can generate a separate code documentation as `mypackage-code.pdf`.

`mypackage.tex` is the user manual, generating `mypackage.pdf`.

This is all good and produces desired results on the LaTeX side of things. The problem occurs because of the way AUCTeX names the auto generated style files for them (those stored in `./auto/`). AUCTeX uses the basename of the file with `.el` extension. But in so doing the generated style files for `mypackage.dtx` and `mypackage.tex` conflict and override each other (technically `mypackage.ins` also conflicts, but it is less frequently edited, so less of a problem, but still...). So that whenever I open either of those files I start to notice things are amiss, until I say "Ah!!!", and call `C-u C-c C-n` to reparse the file. But that's pretty annoying.

So, the question is, is there a way to control on a per-file basis the name of the auto generated style file so that those won't conflict like that? Like a file local variable, or something of the sort?

Failing that, are there any common / known workarounds for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an "one size fits all" solution for your issue.  I'd probably write a `mypackage.el` supporting macros/environments provided by the final product `mypackage.sty` and save that under the directory in `TeX-style-private`, and rely on parsed information in `./auto/mypackage.el` only for the `.dtx` file.  This approach should give you enough flexibility that when you `\usepackage{mypackage}`, only the relevant part is loaded, and when you load your `.dtx` file, both AUCTeX styles are loaded (in theory, at least; I didn't try).

Comment: Arash, Thank you! But wouldn't the parsing of `mypackage.tex` still overwrite that of the `.dtx`? In the meantime, I did some further searching and, given that my main reason not to want to rename the user manual was `texdoc` and that `texdoc` also gives a high score to `mypackage-doc`, I went with that and renamed it.

Comment: Btw, the further search tells me this is an "old decision", so you probably answered this many times. But I really fail to understand why AUCTeX does not name the auto generated style files using the whole file name, like `mypackage.tex.el`, `mypackage.dtx.el` etc.

Comment: @gusbrs - You're welcome.  I don't understand why you want to parse `mypackage.tex` when it is generated from `mypackage.tex`?  Do you edit that file separately?  Reg. naming: I think this had something to do with some OS which couldn't handle long file names correctly, but I can't tell for sure.  At any rate, I think there is a patch to change this behavior, but noone dared to play with it `;-)`

Comment: Yes, I edit the user manual (the `.tex`) file separately, the content is really there, not in the `.dtx`. The `.dtx` is input whole from `mypackage-code.tex` to generate the code documentation, separate from the manual. Regarding the origins of the problem and the patch: I see. :) It's that entangled then...